# How to hide id in url after link click?

Tags: javascript, html

If you would click on the link, you would see the id of the div in your url. How is it possible to hide that?

```css
#one {
  margin-top: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">Link</a>

<div id="one"></div>
```

Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? The fragment feature of URIs is useful for users.

Comment: @Dai I have hidden elements. And if somebody get's a link from a hidden element, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an event listener for `hashchange`, and then set the URL with [`window.history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => window.history.pushState({}, "", '/'), {});
```

```css
#one {
  margin-top: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">Link</a>
<div id="one"></div>
```

Working example here: https://hashchange-pushstate.lcherone.repl.co

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to changes in the window's hash with

`window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => {}, false);`

Then update the url with

`window.history.pushState();`

So you would do

```
function hashHandler() {
    const loc = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
    window.history.pushState({}, 'Page Title', '/' + loc);
}

window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashHandler, false);
```

Note that it only works in Chrome / FF / IE 10+. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)